# (gdb) terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gdb_exception_RETURN_MASK_ERROR'

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have `define` in my `~/.gdbinit` of `as`:

```
set history save on 
set logging file ./.debug_dump
set logging on
set trace-commands on
set history remove-duplicates 256

define as
    layout asm
end

define ras
    layout split
    layout asm
end
```

And, once I in gdb, write `as`, scroll 4 lines, and the error above will terminate the gdb. What had happened?